# inserting data in table in sql from another table records

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables...

- `UserMaster` (`UserID, Fname`)
- `SharingMaster` (`SharingID, UserID`)

I want all data inserted into `SharingMaster` that `UserID` are available in `UserMaster`... means each row per `userid` from `usermaster`....

For example.. if I have data in both tables

**UserMaster**:

```
UserID         Fname
-----------------------
  1         Abc
  4         Def
  5     asda
  8     fgdfgdf
```

and `SharingMaster` as follows

```
SharingID        UserID
-------------------------
  6     1
  9     4
  8     5
  8     8
```

so what is query for that?

Comment: Show us you code so far? Also look into joining tables, because that's what it sounds like you want to do.

Comment: where does the SharingID come from?  Is it already there?

Comment: Also, which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to insert `UserID`s into `SharingMaster` from `UserMaster` that are not already present, here's a way to do it in SQL Server.  My only assumption is that the `SharingID` is an IDENTITY column that will auto populate.

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.SharingMaster
        (UserID
       , Fname
        )
        SELECT  UserID
              , Fname
        FROM    UserMaster
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   SharingMaster
                             WHERE  SharingMaster.UserID = UserMaster.UserID )
```

Then again, since the scenario was a little ambiguous, here are some other options.  My assumption here is that "all the data" you referred to was the `Fname` column from UserMaster.

If you wanted to insert or overwrite existing data for IDs already in sharing master:

```
INSERT  INTO SharingMaster
        (Fname
        )
        SELECT  Fname
        FROM    UserMaster
        JOIN    SharingMaster
                ON UserMaster.UserID = SharingMaster.SharingID
```

And as a bonus, if you're on SQL Server 2008 R2 or above, you can use the MERGE statement:

```
MERGE dbo.SharingMaster AS TARGET
    USING 
        (SELECT UserID
              , Fname
         FROM   dbo.UserMaster
        ) AS SOURCE (UserID, Fname)
    ON (TARGET.UserID = SOURCE.UserID)
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN
UPDATE    SET
        Fname = SOURCE.Fname
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
        THEN 
INSERT  (UserID, Fname)
          VALUES
        (SOURCE.UserID
       , SOURCE.Fname
        );
```